# Arrow Notation Functions

Tags: reduce

The following problem:

`f = (a, x) => a += x;`

Is (the above) equivalent to either of the following?

`f = function(a, x) { return a += x; }`  (This is probably incorrect)

or

`f = function(a, x) {return a + x; }`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try it here: https://babeljs.io/repl/

It's roughly equivalent to the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is under the assumption that you are using Javascript ES6.

Anyway, the answer in javascript is that it's equal to:

```
f = function f(a, x) { return a += x; };
```

Your notation seems ES6 (or Scala :)). You can try it out with online [Babel ES6 to ES5 transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=f%20%3D%20(a%2C%20x)%20%3D%3E%20a%20%2B%3D%20x%3B).